Expo app throws "Network request failed" when installed through APK
I'm working on a personal app to control things on my home through a server running on Flask. I've already made the app, and it works on Expo loaded to my phone through the QR, it send the requests to my server, and everything works correctly, but after I built the APK through expo eas, when I install on my phone, it doesn't work anymore, it throws "Network request failed", and nothing else to guide me into what is the problem. My guess was that Android was probably blocking HTTP requests, since due to this being a server mounted on an RPi for my home, I don't really need to bother into dealing with certificates, so after researching a while, I came with this app.json(Removed private parts), but is still not working.
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "",
    "slug": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "newArchEnabled": true,
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash-icon.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "usesCleartextTraffic": true,
      "package": "",
      "permissions": ["INTERNET"]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": ""
      }
    }
  }
}

I've tested my app through HTTP request shortcuts app, so I know it should be possible to reach my server through an actual Android app, and since the app works on the Expo testing then I'm guessing that I'm not using the fetch library wrong(I didn't install any custom library, just the basic fetch from React). What am I missing to make this work? I've tried to do it like it says in this question, but after installing that library, it messed up my whole project, causing me not to be able to load the application for testing through QR, and only be able to build it and install it, which anyway didn't work, still threw the error. Outside this app.json, I haven't modified any other file, just the defaults Expo files, and my app, and in case is necessary, this is how I handle the request:
const togglePlay = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}toggle`);
      const json = await response.json();

      handleToast(json);
      if (json.status) {
        setIsAnimating((prev) => json.state);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Toast.show({
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Error',
        text2: error.message,
      });
      handleError(error);
    }
  };


After trying a few more times, I managed to make the expo-build-properties work without messing my whole expo project, not sure what caused it, but after managing to install it with npx expo install expo-build-properties, I just had to add this to my app.json, and it worked
"plugins":[
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "usesCleartextTraffic": true,
      }
    },
  ],
]

